Snubber circuit design for a sensitive gate TRIAC
I am designing a snubber circuit for a TRIAC used to drive an RL load. The problem is that I do not know the exact inductance of the load.
The load is a resistance comprised of wrapped wire forming a coil, so its inductance cannot be ignored. Below you will find the circuit in LTspice with simulation results. I'm unsure if the results are correct.
Why does the TRIAC block the negative half-wave even though a firing signal is present? A firing signal is sent to the gate of the TRIAC via a 1:1 transformer. Since this is a university project, we can only work with a maximum of 36V RMS. The TRIAC model used is similar to the one we plan to purchase. I had to improvise due to the limitations of available Spice models.

Is the simulation correct?
Am I missing something?



Lowering R1 to 50 ohms produces a different behavior:


Simulated TRIAC
TRIAC to be bought
Snubber design
Another source for RC snubber


Exact inductance might not be known, but is the maximum inductance knowable? Perhaps you have winding details/drawings of the heater?

No unfortunately not.

This TRIAC needs different trigger currents in different quadrants.
With R1 = 100 Ω we see a bit more than 20 mA peak, which seams to be sufficient for the positive half wave but not for the negative.
The time between TRIAC turn off and the new trigger is very short. With a lower load inductance the negative trigger may be successful at this ignition angle.
With R1 = 50 Ω we see above 30 mA peak, good enough for both quadrants.
So, yes, the simulator output looks plausible.
The assumed load inductance is 1 H in your schematic, which sounds very large in this context.
